# Twitter rate limiting confusion?

Tags: twitter, social-networking, rate-limiting

So I'm currently using [NodeXL](http://nodexl.codeplex.com/) to get search for a particular Twitter hashtag, and I'm having trouble on understand how exactly the rate-limiting works. I looked it up in Twitter's [API Rate Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting) page, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305547/how-rate-limit-works-in-twitter-in-search-api) SO  post, but even after reading both, I don't really understand. The API page says:

> Search will be limited at 180 queries per 15 minute window for the time being.

and also

> Rate limiting in version 1.1 of the API is primarily considered on a per-user basis — or more accurately described, per access token in your control. If a method allows for 15 requests per rate limit window, then it allows you to make 15 requests per window per leveraged access token.

But I'm totally confused... probably because I've never really worked with anything database, or social network analysis before.

When it says that it always 180 queries per 15 minutes, what exactly constitutes a query? The way the search works on NodeXL is that you limit the amount of tweets you are searching for. So if I search once and set my tweet limit to 1000 tweets, is that only 1 query?

Sorry if this seems like a stupid or really elementary question, but I just don't have any experience with this stuff at all, and any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When it says that it always 180 queries per 15 minutes, what exactly
>   constitutes a query?

Whenever you make one request to `Twitter`, its considered as one query. For `Search API` you can make 180 calls per 15 minute.

> So if I search once and set my tweet limit to 1000 tweets, is that
>   only 1 query?

Yes, but you can't set count to 1000 since the maximum tweets you can return per request is 100 as it mentioned [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets).

You can retrieve the latest 100 tweets with the normal search query and for pagination you should use `since_id` and `max_id` to retrieve the next 100 tweets for fresh tweets.

The number of queries you can make per 15 min windows varies by `API`. For example, you can query 180 requests per 15 min window if you use `Search API`. But, if you use `API` like `GET friends/ids`, it's limited to 15 query per 15 min windows. i.e you can make call only 15 times per 15 minutes.

Here's the [Rate limits chart](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits) where you can find how many requests you can make per 15 window for each `API`.

Comment: ohhh I see....thank you!! So basically then for that 1000 tweets, I made 10 requests? I don't understand what you mean by I can't set count to 1000.

Comment: Yes. Your first call will get latest 100 tweets and to get 101-200, you need to use `since_id` and `max_id` parameters along with your query like `count`that will fetch you the next 100 tweets. Similarly you need to fetch the old tweets. But, there's a limitation that [Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search). You can use `Streaming API` if you want to fetch the tweets from present to future not past.