# Twitter API will take foreover to get followers list

Tags: api, twitter

मैं एक विशेष प्रयोक्ता का अनुसरण करने वाले लोगों के आंकडे को प्राप्त कर उस पर कुछ तर्क लगा कर कुछ उत्तम प्रयोक्ताओं को प्राप्त करने का इच्छुक हूँ । मुझे ट्विट्टर के अनुप्रयोग तंत्रांश अंतर्फलक को प्रत्येक १५ मिनट में केवल १५ बार आवाह्न कर पाने का पता चला । तो मैंने [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list) इकाई का प्रयोग किया और केवल २० परिणाम प्राप्त कर पाने में सफल रहा व प्रत्येक १५ मिनट में केवल १५ ही आवाह्म हो सकते हैं । तो इसका अर्थ हुआ :

- १५ मिनट में ३०० अनुयायियों का आँकडा
- १ घंटे में १२०० अनुयायियों का आँकडा

तो मान लीजिये मुझे [भारत के प्रधानमंत्री श्री नरेन्द्र मोदी जी](https://twitter.com/narendramodi) के अनुयायियों का आँकडा पाना है तो :

- नरेन्द्र मोदी जी के अनुयायी : १.४५ करोड़

**अनुयायियों का आँकडा पाने में लगने वाला समय : १२०८३ घंटे -> ५०३ दिवस -> १.३७ वर्ष**

क्या मैं कुछ गलत कर रहा हूँ या फिर ट्विट्टर से आँकडा पाने में ही कठिनाई है ?

---

I thought of getting followers data for a particular user and run the obtained data through some logic to filter out some worthy users. And I came to know of 15 calls in 15 mins rule. So I use the endpoint [https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list) and I can get just 20 results in one request and there are just 15 requests per 15 minutes. So this means :

- 15 mins  -> 300 followers data
- 1 hour -> 1200 followers data

To get follower data of e.g. [Mr. Narendra Modi, The Prime Minister of Bharat (a.k.a. India )](https://twitter.com/narendramodi)

- Narendra Modi followers: 14.5 million

**Time to get followers data with the rate limit: 12083 hours -> 503 days -> 1.37 years**

Am I doing this wrong or is it really tough to get data from Twitter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad new is that it is difficult. However, the good news is that there are a couple things that will improve your situation: *count* and *application authorization*.

Your calculations are based on the default number of items returned, **20**, but you can use the *count* parameter to increase that to **200**. That improves your results to **3000** and **12000** in 15 minutes and 1 hour, respectively.

For rate limits, you can reference the following Rate Limit Chart:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

This indicates that the number of requests for user authorization is **15**. However, you also have the option of *application authorization* and that number of requests is **30** in the 15 minute time window.

This effectively doubles the rate, giving you **6000** and **24000** results in the 15 and 1 hour times, respectively, by both increasing *count* and switching to *application authorization*.

Here's an earlier post on rate limits with the search API that might also give you ideas:

[How rate limit works in twitter in search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305547/how-rate-limit-works-in-twitter-in-search-api/21316883#21316883)

Comment: इस तंत्रांश के लिये प्रयोक्ता की जानकारी आवश्यक है तो तंत्रांश आधारित प्राधिकृति का प्रयोग तो नहीं कर पाऊँगा पर हाँ ये काउन्ट मापदण्ड का प्रयोग कर १.७ साल को ५० दिनों में तो करा ही जा सकता है । ये अच्छा रहेगा । 

------------------

User information is necessary for this solution so App authentication can't be used but yeah, with the use of count parameter atleast 1.3 years can be brought down to 50 days. This seems OK for now.