# How to get most influential followers of a twitter user?

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to find the top most followers based on the number of tweets about a brand named Maybelline on Twitter. The brand has about 600K followers and when I try to retrieve them the code keeps running for hours. So is there an efficient way to do this? I am using the below code after setting up twitter authentication. I want all the followers ( top 50) who tweeted the most about Maybelline.

```
user<-getUser('Maybelline')
user$toDataFrame()
followers<-user$getFollowers()
```

Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer to give you an alternative that would take most at most 8 hours assuming the twitter R package supports these methods/calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While working with the Twitter API, it's useful to familiarize yourself with their limits.  You have two main limits for a `GET` request, one is a Rate Limit (how many requests you can make in a 15 minute timeframe) and the other is the limit of how many results a certain call gives you.

In your scenario, you are using the `GET followers/list` endpoint from their API.  You can read the docs for that [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list).  That endpoint returns a list of followers and is limited to 20 followers per request and 15 request per 15 minutes, meaning that in a 15 minute timeframe, you can only retrieve `15*20 = 300` users.  So to retrieve 600K followers that would take a *very* long time ( 30K minutes = 500 hours = ~21 days ).

It would be more efficient to use the `GET followers/id` which returns up to 5K user ids with each request with the same 15 request per 15 minute rate limit.  Twitter API reference [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids). You can use this in conjunction with the Twitter `GET users/lookup` which returns up to 100 users per request and has a rate limit of 900 requests per 15 minutes.  This means it would take 2 hours (at 75K users per 15 minute increment) to get 600K followers id's.  And less than 2 hours to get the user objects ( at 90K users per 15 minutes ).

The rate limits can change depending on how the package you are using does authentication.  If you are logging in as a Twitter user with your credentials, then the above rate limits are correct.  If you are using only application credentials, then getting the followers will take 3x longer as `users/lookup` has a rate limit of 300 requests in that case or 30K users per 15 minutes.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305547/how-rate-limit-works-in-twitter-in-search-api) has some good information on rate limits.